# Replacing nested for loops and value assignment for list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, list-comprehension

I've written a function to count the occurences of certain characters (`A`, `C`, `G` and `T`) within multiple strings at the same position and save the number of occurrences in a dictionary.

For example with these two strings 'ACGG' and 'CAGT', it should return:

```
{'A': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'C': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'G': [0, 0, 2, 1], 'T': [0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

I want to convert the code below to list comprehension to optimize it for speed. It uses two nested for loops, and the input Motifs is a list of strings containing A's C's G's and T's.

```
def CountWithPseudocounts(Motifs):
    count = {}
    k = len(Motifs[0])
    t = len(Motifs)
    for s in 'ACGT':
        count[s] = [0] * k
    for i in range(t):
        for j in range(k):
            symbol = Motifs[i][j]
            count[symbol][j] += 1
return count
```

I've tried replacing the nested for loops at the bottom of the function for this list comprehension:

```
count = [ [ count[Motifs[i][j]][j] += 1 ] for i in range(0, t) ] for j in range(0, k)]
```

It doesn't work, probably because I'm not allowed to do the value assignment of += 1 within the list comprehension. How can I work around this?

Comment: The strings are guaranteed to have the same length?

Comment: Yes they are guaranteed to have the same length

Comment: _"I want to convert the code below to list comprehension to optimize it for speed"_ - Why do you think a list comprehension would be faster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can indeed not do assignments in list comprehension (well you can - by calling functions - perform side effects). A list comprehension expects an expression. Furthermore it is weird that you want to assign to `count` and at the same time update an old `count`.

A way to do this with *dictionary comprehension* and *list comprehension* that is not very efficient is:

```
chars = 'ACGT'

a = 'ACGG'
b = 'CAGT'

sequences = list(zip(a,b))

counts = {char:[seq.count(char) for seq in sequences] for char in chars}
```

(credits to [@Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672276/replacing-nested-for-loops-and-value-assignment-for-list-comprehension/42672549#comment72470230_42672549) for the `seq.count(char)` suggestion)

This produces:

```
{'G': [0, 0, 2, 1], 'A': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'C': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'T': [0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

You can easily generalize the solution to count more strings by calling `zip(..)` with more strings.

You can also decide to optimize your algorithm itself. This will probably be more effective since then you only have to loop over the strings once and you can use the lookup of a dictionary, like:

```
def CountWithPseudocounts(sequences):
    k = len(sequences[0])
    count = {char:[0]*k for char in 'ACGT'}
    for sequence in sequences:
        j = 0
        for symbol in sequence:
            count[symbol][j] += 1
            j += 1
    return count
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to add one to all elements in the counts you can use:

```
counts = {char:[seq.count(char)+1 for seq in sequences] for char in chars}
```

Comment: why are you wrapping `zip` to a `list` (`list(zip(a,b))`)?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: because of performance reasons: otherwise you have to calculate the `zip(..)` each time. Now the tuples are constructed only once.

Comment: Oh, True. Thanks!

Comment: why not use `seq.count(char)` instead of `sum()`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: that is indeed a good suggestion and will probably boost performance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've used you're rewrite of my algorithm with the for loops and it was about 15% faster. I'd still like to try your solution with the dictionary comprehension. But I'm having a problem now with using zip on my list of strings. How do I go from: Motifs = ['ACGG' and 'CAGT'] to zip(Motifs)?
I understand that zip always requires two arguments, but how do I get zip to go over all the strings in my list?

Comment: @DavidK11: I assume that you mean `Motifs = ['ACGG','CAGT']` with a comma (`and` will also work, but that is something different). You can use `zip(*Motifs)` (with an asterisk `*`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Ah yes of course I meant to write it with a comma. The asterisk works, thanks! 
Now a final question: I meant to add pseudocounts in the count dictionary, is there a way in the dictionary comprehension to add 1 to each number in count?

Comment: @DavidK11: I do not follow, do you want `{'G': [1, 1, 3, 2], 'A': [2, 2, 1, 1],...}`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yes exactly that's what I mean by pseudocounts.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `zip()`:

```
In [10]: a = 'ACGG'           

In [11]: b = 'CAGT'

In [12]: chars = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'] 

In [13]: [[(ch==i) + (ch==j) for i, j in zip(a, b)] for ch in chars]
Out[13]: [[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

If you want a dictionary you can use a dict comprehension:

```
In [25]: {ch:[(ch==i) + (ch==j) for i, j in zip(a, b)] for ch in chars}
Out[25]: {'T': [0, 0, 0, 1], 'G': [0, 0, 2, 1], 'C': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'A': [1, 1, 0, 0]}
```

Or if you want the result in same order as your character list, you can use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
In [26]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [27]: OrderedDict((ch, [(ch==i) + (ch==j) for i, j in zip(a, b)]) for ch in chars)
Out[28]: OrderedDict([('A', [1, 1, 0, 0]), ('C', [1, 1, 0, 0]), ('G', [0, 0, 2, 1]), ('T', [0, 0, 0, 1])])
```

If you still need more performance and/or you're dealing with long strings and larger data sets you can use Numpy to get around this problem though a vectorized method.

```
In [61]: pairs = np.array((list(a), list(b))).T

In [62]: chars
Out[62]: 
array(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [63]: (chars[:,None,None] == pairs).sum(2)
Out[63]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest the numpy approach provided by @Kasramvs if speed performance really matters.

Moreover, counting chars is not friendly even to modern computers and perhaps you can play with some tricks about indexing/hashing of the input strings before counting.  For example, since every string has only 4 chars, and each char does only contain 4 possible letters, 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', therefore it can easily represent each of all the 'ACGT' combinations from 'AAAA' to 'TTTT' with a number, a hash or a mysterious code.  The volume of the combinations should be equal to or less than 4x4x4x4=256 different numbers here.

And then count the code instead.  Such as, every time you see an 'AAAA' and then you count it as 0x0 in a python list or a numpy array, see an 'AAAC' and count as 0x1, and vice versa.  After that, you'll get a binning array with indices ranging from 0x0 ~ 0xFF(255) and with the corresponding occurrences, right?  Now remember, one 0x0 stands for A:{1, 1, 1, 1} in your case, or seven 0x1 for A:{7, 7, 7, 0} along with C:{0, 0, 0, 7}... Sum them all carefully and it's the result.

These kind of tricks should possibly help boost the speed performance quite a lot in this case.  The speed benefits in two factors: the first one is that now computers are dealing with numbers instead of chars while numbers are much easier to sort, count, group, partition or index than chars; the second one comes from a much higher cache hit rate by the nature since the memory trace is reduced a lot in these tricks.

I hope this may help. :)

Well, add some codes as follows to be a clear reference.

First of all, imports:

```
    import itertools
    import numpy as np
```

And the function `encode_sequence()` below should be fast enough provided dict `t02` is not too large, say, typically less than 1M key-value pairs:

```
    def encode_sequence(tsq):
        t00 = itertools.product('ACGT', repeat=4)
        t01 = np.array(list(t00)).view('|U4').ravel()

        t02 = dict(zip(t01, np.arange(len(t01))))

        t03 = [t02[i] for i in tsq]

        return t03
```

And use the following snippet to generate a tensor, `map_decode`, to represent stuffs about ``counting the code''... Also, there is a math trick called augmented matrix transform beneath this part, saying that it transforms `ll0` and `'ACGT'` in the same manner to span `map_decode` for later use.

```
    ll0 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    map_decode = np.array(list(itertools.product(ll0, repeat=4)))
```

Feed a test sequence and translate,

```
    test_seq = ('ACGG', 'CAGT', 'CCGA', 'AAAT', 'TTGC', 'GCAT', 'ACGG', 'AAAT')
    u01 = encode_sequence(test_seq)
```

Count the occurrences; beware that the block below should be the major source of speed gain because the computer is good at handling numbers in `u01`,

```
    p01, q01 = np.unique(u01, return_counts=True)
```

After all, generate the output... It is a bit tricky here, such as `p01` is the *sorted hash code* of `test_seq` and `q01` is indeed the corresponding counts while `map_decode` serves as what I said, a tensor to map a hash code in `p01` to another vector we want, e.g., mapping 0x0 (or 'AAAA') to A:[1, 1, 1, 1], C:[0, 0, 0, 0], G:[0, 0, 0, 0] and T:[0, 0, 0, 0].  The mapped `map_decode[p01]` is thus weighted by counts `q01` and ready to sum for the report:

```
    np.sum(map_decode[p01]*q01[:, None, None], axis=0).T
```

And it says,

```
    array([[4, 3, 3, 1],
           [2, 4, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 5, 2],
           [1, 1, 0, 4]])
```

which is equivalent to A:{4, 3, 3, 1}, C:{2, 4, 0, 1}, G:{1, 0, 5, 2} and T:{1, 1, 0, 4}.  Check to see if it meets the answer.

That's the numpy implementation; it contains no explicit loop in the main body.  And more than that, `encode_sequence()` can be replaced by some offline preparations of inputs to increase the performance in advance.  Though I did not have the speed measure of the above snippets, I think they should be accelerated to a certain degree. :)

---

Ok, let's discuss what will happen if there are long strings.

We use this sequence as an example,

```
    test_seq0 = ((
            'A'*40, 'A'*40, 'A'*40, 'C'*40, 'C'*40,
            'C'*40, 'C'*40, 'G'*40, 'G'*40, 'T'*40
        ))*4
```

The `test_seq0` contains 40 strings and each string has 40 chars.  It looks like this,

```
    In: len(test_seq0), test_seq0
    Out: (40,
           ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
            'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
            'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
                     ... skip 30 lines ...
            'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
            'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
            'GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG',
            'GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG',
            'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT'))
```

Quite a funny view, right?

Then we have to refit the `encode_sequence()` for a long string version,

```
    def encode_sequence_longstring(tsq_np):
        t00 = itertools.product('ACGT', repeat=4)
        t01 = np.array(list(t00)).view('|U4').ravel()

        t02 = dict(zip(t01, np.arange(len(t01))))

        t03 = np.empty_like(tsq_np, dtype=np.uint)
        t03.ravel()[:] = [t02[i] for i in tsq_np.ravel()]

        return t03
```

Be careful that `tsq_np` here is no longer a simple list of strings.  The postfix `_np` means it's now a numpy array.

And divide the original `test_seq0` by a numpy way,

```
    In: v01 = np.asarray(test_seq0).view('|U4').reshape(-1, int(40/4))
    In: v01
    Out: 
    array([['AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA'],
           ['AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA'],
           ['AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA'],
           ['CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC'],
           ['CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC'],
                ... skip 30 lines ...
           ['CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC'],
           ['CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCC'],
           ['GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG'],
           ['GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG', 'GGGG'],
           ['TTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTTT']], 
          dtype='<U4')
```

Another funny view in `v01`. :)

And use `v01` to compute the hash codes `u02` like this.  It involves some numpy conventions around these variables and functions.  Just get used to those fancy tricks; they worth it,

```
    In: u02 = encode_sequence_longstring(v01)
    In: u02
    Out: 
    array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
           [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
           [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
           [ 85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85],
           [ 85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85],
               ... skip 30 lines ...
           [ 85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85],
           [ 85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85,  85],
           [170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170],
           [170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170],
           [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]],
       dtype=uint64)
```

By observation, you can tell `u02` is actually a 1-to-1 mapping of `v01`.  It just maps each 'AAAA' to 0x0 as expected.

From now on, the map `u02` contains the whole information you need regarding to `test_seq0`.  Extract it out of `u02` with the help of numpy,

```
    s01 = np.empty((4, 0))
    for u03 in u02.T:
        p02, q02 = np.unique(u03, return_counts=True)
        s02 = np.sum(map_decode[p02]*q02[:, None, None], axis=0).T
        s01 = np.hstack((s01, s02))
```

There's a thumb rule for python's native loop: you can use it, but use it outside of any performance-sensitive region.  But, that needs experiences to judge the situation on hand.

Now `s01` is the expected report as follows,

```
    In: s01
    Out:
    array([[ 12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,
             12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,
             12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,
             12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.,  12.],
           [ 16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,
             16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,
             16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,
             16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.],
           [  8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,
              8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,
              8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,
              8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.,   8.],
           [  4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,
              4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,
              4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,
              4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.]])
```

Read the 4 rows from top to bottom and they are 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', respectively.

At the same time, I've tried a 40x10x4000 `test_seq0` like this,

```
    test_seq0 = ((
            'A'*40, 'A'*40, 'A'*40, 'C'*40, 'C'*40,
            'C'*40, 'C'*40, 'G'*40, 'G'*40, 'T'*40
        ))*4000
```

The report says,

```
    array([[ 12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,
             12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,
             12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,
             12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,
             12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,
             12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.,  12000.],
           [ 16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,
             16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,
             16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,
             16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,
             16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,
             16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.,  16000.],
           [  8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,
              8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,
              8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,
              8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,
              8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,
              8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.,   8000.],
           [  4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,
              4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,
              4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,
              4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,
              4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,
              4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.,   4000.]])
```

and it is finished in less than 1 second (press ENTER, and it's done) on my MacBook Pro, which is not a monster. :)

Comment: I've implemented this approach, however when I test on a test sequence with strings of 10 characters it becomes very slow in comparison to my approach with the nested for loops. I've replaced 'repeat=4' with 'repeat=k' where I've set k=10. Furthermore I changed '|U4' to '|U10'. When I analyze the runtime with Snakeviz it seems like the vast majority of time is spent on the numpy array (I'm not sure whether building the array or reading from it). Is this because the array increases quadratically?

Comment: I think it is.  The volume of hash keys required for 10 chars length will increase to 4*4*4*4...*4, or 4^10, leading to about 1M, which is what I expect to be an upper limit of my implementation.  You'll also have a vast tensor in `map_decode`.  Try to divide 10 chars to sub-strings like 5 chars + 5 chars since you just need the occurrences on a position.  Count them independently and then concatenate them.  That should be easy to implement by numpy.vstack() or numpy.hstack() depending on your array layout. :)

Comment: I forgot to note, a large array for indexing (e.g `t02` or `map_decode` in this case) is very harmful to performance for both the storage size and the speed.  The CPU architectures favor a very small chunk to fit in their tiny cache, and operating systems define another performance bound by how they handle memory and swap, generally leading to a good choice of an expected-to-be-fast array to be sized in less than several pages.  Keep that in mind when choosing a divide-and-conquer design. :)

Comment: I extended the illustration to long strings in addition.

Answer (score 0):

collections.Counter is your friend :)

```
s1 = 'ACGG'
s2 = 'CAGT'

from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(enumerate(s1))
counter += Counter(enumerate(s2))
```

Output format: ((position, character), number of occurrences)

```
sorted(counter.items())
[((0, 'A'), 1),
 ((0, 'C'), 1),
 ((1, 'A'), 1),
 ((1, 'C'), 1),
 ((2, 'G'), 2),
 ((3, 'G'), 1),
 ((3, 'T'), 1)]

[counter[i,'A'] if (i,'A') in counter else 0 for i in range(4)]
[1, 1, 0, 0]

[counter[i,'C'] if (i,'C') in counter else 0 for i in range(4)]
[1, 1, 0, 0]

[counter[i,'G'] if (i,'G') in counter else 0 for i in range(4)]
[0, 0, 2, 1]

[counter[i,'T'] if (i,'T') in counter else 0 for i in range(4)]   
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```